# How to disable AutoComplete/Autosuggestion option in Sails Js CLI console?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, sails.js

I'm new in `sails.js` and i'm trying to start **sails.js cli console** (`sails console`). but there is one problem which i'm facing in the console which makes it difficult to use and that is **autocomplete/autosuggestion** option. i have attached a screenshot as an example of the cause. The problem is whenever i try to type something in the console the autosuggestion keeps pops up which makes remaining characters flyaway from the line.

I tried both in **Mac Os** terminal and **Visual Studio Code** terminal both resulted the same. I also tried checking for any configuration option in order to disable it but i couldn't find any. So it will be great help if anyone can help me to understand or a solution for this thanks in advance.

> Node Version: v14.13.0

> Sails Version: 1.2.4

[image: screenshot]